# Is it possible to store data from post request into a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, backend

I made a simple POST request to fetch data from a search bar into backend. I am able to console.log it - but I need to be able to store that information (as a variable/const ideally) and IF it fits the criteria, I need to be able to add it into a function in the backend and return data based on that function. Is this possible with a PUT request or should I use query.params ?

```
app.post("/search", (req, res) => {
    const result = req.body;
    res.send({
        search: result,
    });
});
```

1. Pull data from search bar into backend
2. Run a function using the searched keyword
3. Return new information based around the keyword

for reference - here's the function that I would like to enter the searched keyword into for every instance of **searchBarResultHere** ( and there's 7 of them )

```
async function **searchBarResultHere**() {


    const html = await request.get(
        "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/**searchBarResultHere**/"
        );

    const $ = await cheerio.load(html);

    const Price = $('[class="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"]').text();
    const Symbol = $('[class="D(ib) Fz(18px)"]').text();
    const PercentChange = $('fin-streamer[class="Fw(500) Pstart(8px) Fz(24px)"][data-field="regularMarketChangePercent"]').find('span').text();


    await connectToMongoDB();
     // fetch stock/crypto data

    const listingModel = new **searchBarResultHere**({
        price: Price, 
        symbol: Symbol, 
        percentChange: PercentChange,
    });
    
    // save into MongoDB Modal
    await listingModel.save();

    // UPDATE stock price if it changed
    await Stock.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            symbol: **searchBarResultHere**,
        }, 
        {
        price: Price, 
        symbol: **searchBarResultHere**, 
        percentChange: PercentChange,
        },
        {
            upsert: true
        }
        );

    
    
        console.log(Price)
    setTimeout(**searchBarResultHere**, 1000000); // 60 seconds == 1minute // not needed with node-cron


    
   
}

**searchBarResultHere**();
```

in a nutshell this is a program that goes on yahoo.finance and periodically records some chosen text fields from the yahoo.finance website.. then stores & displays it back into HTML with Stock/Crypto Name, Price and 24 hour change

I want to let people type in a stock name (or symbol), and make the program fetch all the data for them so they can see it without having to go on yahoo finance :)

But I'm struggling to figure out how to make the connection between seaching for a stock name and sending the search result to the backend function to fetch all data from yahoo.finance.

Comment: Given  `async` functions can't be used as constructors, and `const` variables can't be set asynchronously,  consider using **searchBarResultHere** as a property name of a dictionary object, and as a parameter passed between functions?

Comment: I talked to a friend of mine - he also recommended this approach, something like:
app.post("/search",  (req, res) => {
const result = req.body;
someFunction(result);
});

Thanks tho, it helps to know that its the right way to go.

Comment: .. It's early days,  but if `someFunction`  returns a promise  `result =` will need an `await` after it, or occur in a `then` handler of the returned promise ...